How does BERT know how to where to add segment embeddings (i.e. to differentiate between two sentences packed in a single token sequence)
In addition to using a special [SEP] token to distinguish between two sentences, I understand that BERT also adds special learned embeddings to each sentence:
"we add a learned embedding to every token indicating whether it belongs
to sentence A or sentence B" (from the BERT paper)
To my understanding, BERT has no way of differentiating between the two sentences in the raw input apart from the [SEP] token between them, but the model architecture doesn't specifically recognize this as a special token; (from my understanding) the model learns to treat this as a separating token while pretraining (Is this correct? I'm not too sure about whether I understand this part correctly either). If this is true, how does the model know where to add the additional learned embedding to sentence A and B (i.e. how does it know which part of the input sequence is A and which part is B, so it can add the additional embeddings appropriately)?
Just a quick note that I am not very familiar with these topics, so please correct me if there are any additional bugs in my understanding that you can pick out! This would be very appreciated--I am quite certain I'm missing some key understanding here.
